# Nullpointer exception when drawing ImageIcons

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to create graphics for a very simple 2D game. I have arrayLists of imageIcons that will get drawn in succession when the player moves. One for up, one for down, etc. As of right now, I do not have the finished sprites so I replaced each separate one with a temporary image.

```
//this is inside the constructor

playerUp.add(new ImageIcon("Player1.png"); //will be a different image, but this image still exists
playerUp.add(new ImageIcon("Player1.png"); //will be a different image, but this image still exists
playerUp.add(new ImageIcon("PLayer1.png"); //will be a different image, but this image still exists
```

Then I draw them to an offscreen image that I later draw to the screen to prevent flickering.

```
//offg is the graphics object of the offscreen image and g is for the panel

offg.clearRect(0, 0, panel.getWidth(), panel.getHeight());
playerUp.get(0).paintIcon(panel, offg, x, y);
g.drawImage(offscreen, 0, 0, panel); //this is where the error occurs!
```

Anyways There is some kind of error in the code I tried using:

```
playerUp.add(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Player1.png")));
```

but I do not know if I needed to, or how to use it properly (when researching I saw it a lot), however, That did not fix the problem. Also, I made sure that the image is in the same folder as the .class and .java files.

Also, I created a separate class that just drew an ImageIcon straight to the panel, and it used a completely different image.

```
ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("downlaodedimage.png"); //downlaodedimage.png is the different image

ii.paintIcon(panel, g, 0, 0);
```

And that gives a null pointer exception. I used:

```
System.out.println(ii);
```

And it printed out downloadedimage.png, so I do not know what the issue is?

Comment: What's the exact error? And have you tried debugging this?

Comment: If `g.drawImage` is giving you a null pointer exception, that seems to indicate that `g` is null.

Comment: `Then I draw them to an offscreen image that I later draw to the screen to prevent flickering.` - Swing is double buffered by default. This step is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

the issue is that something on that line hasn't been initialized yet.  Try debugging it to find which one is null, and making sure it is initialized prior to the call. Alternatively, if this occurs during a game loop, and the variable is initialized later in the loop, you can surround it with a try - catch to wait until the variable has been initialized.